# javascript animation - buttons using previous end point

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have a bar slide up and down over the below image, based on certain values triggered by buttons. Ideally the new "start" position every time is the previously entered "end" position (unless there is a better method). Here is the
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pLSG.png)

My code below accomplished most of what I want, except I'd love to have the bar smoothly slide between the desired values after each button click. Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</script>

</body>
</html>

<style>
#container {
  width: 19px;
  height: 186px;
  position: relative;
  background: clear;
margin: 0px; 
}
#animate {
border: 1px solid white;

  width: 32px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #252525;
}

</style>
<body>

<p>
<button onclick="myMove(0 ,20)">Move to Orange</button>
<button onclick="myMove(20, 100)">Move to Green</button>
<button onclick="myMove(100, 155)">Move to Blue</button>
</p> 

<div id ="container">
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/377009668/webGL/stuff/legendVertical.png" alt="Fit Map Legend" style="float:left">
<div id ="animate"></div>
</div>

<script>
function myMove(start, stop) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
 

  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (start == stop) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      start++; 
      elem.style.top = start + 'px'; 
      
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why `null` in `myMove(null, 5)` ??

Answer (score 0):

1. Amazing smooth animation using **CSS3 transition**
2. Use of **`data-*` attribute** instead of inline JS calls
3. **Simple JS** code

```js
var moveBtn = document.querySelectorAll("[data-move]");
var bar = document.getElementById("animate");

function move(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(){
    bar.style.transform = "translateY("+ this.dataset.move +"px)";
  });
}

[].forEach.call(moveBtn, move);
```

```css
#container {
  width: 19px;
  height: 186px;
  position: relative;
}
#animate {
  border: 3px solid #444;
  width: 14px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
          transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<p>
<button data-move="20">Move to Orange</button>
<button data-move="100">Move to Green</button>
<button data-move="170">Move to Blue</button>
</p> 

<div id ="container">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pLSG.png" alt="Fit">
<div id="animate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this approach seems to be more stable. How might I be able to set an initial position onload?... perhaps <body onload=data-move="100">

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the bar slide smoothly to the next position, rather than sliding from the top again, you need to know where the bar currently is starting from.

This can be achieved in a few ways, either by having a global variable store the current position, or by recalculating the current position of it each time you call myMove.

The other thing you need to take into account is that the slider may need to slide up to get to the correct position, not just down. This is easiest to handle in the same if/else statement that you are already using to check if the bar is already in the correct position.

Example using a global variable to keep track of the current position:

(as a bonus myMove() no longer needs to be given a starting location as a parameter, just the location you want the bar to end up at).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</script>

</body>
</html>

<style>
#container {
  width: 19px;
  height: 186px;
  position: relative;
  background: clear;
margin: 0px; 
}
#animate {
border: 1px solid white;

  width: 32px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #252525;
}

</style>
<body>

<p>
<button onclick="myMove(20)">Move to Orange</button>
<button onclick="myMove(100)">Move to Green</button>
<button onclick="myMove(5)">Move to Blue</button>
</p> 

<div id ="container">
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/377009668/webGL/stuff/legendVertical.png" alt="Fit Map Legend" style="float:left">
<div id ="animate"></div>
</div>

<script>
var start = 0;
function myMove(stop) {

  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
 

  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (start == stop) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else if (start > stop){
      start--;
      elem.style.top = start + 'px';
    } else {
      start++; 
      elem.style.top = start + 'px'; 
      
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After multiple clicks the animation starts to act inappropriately :D